# MVC Pass IList Object to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, parameter-passing, ilist

I have an IList object defined as`IList<className> name` where classname is

```
public class ClassName{
    public AnotherClass object{get; set;}
    public string str {get; set;}
 }

public class AnotherClass{
   public string firstname{get; set;}
}
```

My view uses the IList of class name. I loop though it like this

```
for(int i = 0; i < Model.count; i++)
{
  @Html.hiddenFor(m => m[i].object.firstname)
 }
```

When I pass an item of Classname to the controller and try to retrieve firstname of object in that item, "object" is null.

That is

```
[httpPost]
public ActionResult result(Classname model)
{
   string isitnull = model.object.firstname//yiels an error because model.object is null
 }
```

What am i doing wrong please?